# Line with breaks plot style not working in pine script

Tags: plot, line, pine-script-v5

I've this indicator coded in pine script which shows certain daily horizontal levels. But, when the plot style is set to "line with breaks", the vertical line joining the levels are still visible just like plot style "lines". But it works fine when "circles" or "cross" style is selected.

Please help me to fix this issue.

`//@version=5`

```
indicator(title="fff", overlay=true)

// Get user input
disableRepaint = input.bool(title ="Disable Repainting?", defval=true)

pdl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[disableRepaint and barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1]) 

pdh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", high[disableRepaint and barstate.isconfirmed ? 0 : 1])


P1 = (pdh-(pdh-pdl) * 0.756)

P2 = (pdl+(pdh-pdl) * 0.790)



//gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off) //Does not repaint

plot(pdl,style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.gray)

plot(pdh,style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.gray)

plot(P1,style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.white, linewidth=2)

plot(P2,style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.white,linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to your code so it's difficult to help
But, it could look like this

```
plot(P1 == P1[1] ? P1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.white, linewidth=2)

plot(P2 == P2[1] ? P2 : na,  style=plot.style_linebr,color=color.white,linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Hi, I've added full script. Please check that. I tried the one you suggested above . It works fine, but still it give 3 candle gap on the chart.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce that gap so that levels appear at the start of the next day. Or is it possible to extend this plot till the end of present trading session?